# C++ VS2015: Property pages are sharing settings?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I have a VS2015 c++ project I'm trying to set preprocessor settings for.

When I open the configuration manager and change the configuration to "Debug" and then set my preprocessor setting, when I click "Apply" and then switch the configuration to "Release", release adopts whatever I set the debug setting to.

Basically, VS is refusing to let me set different settings for different configurations. Is there some "share settings" option I've accidentally enabled somewhere? How do I get VS to stop sharing settings between configurations?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get property page settings to respect their configuration by adding "condition" tags to the .vcxproj file for those settings.

So

```
<AdditionalDependencies>math.lib</AdditionalDependencies>
```

became

```
<AdditionalDependencies Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">math.lib</AdditionalDependencies>
```

Now when I open VS and switch between configurations, the settings respect their configuration.

However, if anyone knows why VS isn't automatically adding these conditions itself I'd love to hear why.